# How to make a graph (nodes and edges) on Latex?

Tags: graph, latex, nodes, graph-theory

I new coding in latex and I want to make high-quality graphs (nodes and edges), in particular, I need to make this kind of plots.[image: graph]

Is it that even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not only "*even* possible", that is *always* possible. This sort of diagram can be easily created using Ti*k*Z and similar packages.

If you already have the coordinates of the nodes, the directions of the arrows etc., you may start from this. This is **not** your diagram, but is a good starting point.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows} % Shadows for nodes
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{% This is the style settings for nodes
    dep/.style={circle,minimum size=1cm,fill=orange!20,draw=orange,
                general shadow={fill=gray!60,shadow xshift=1pt,shadow yshift=-1pt}},
    cli/.style={circle,minimum size=1cm,fill=white,draw,
                general shadow={fill=gray!60,shadow xshift=1pt,shadow yshift=-1pt}},
    spl/.style={cli,append after command={
                  node[circle,draw,dotted,
                       minimum size=1.5cm] at (\tikzlastnode.center) {}}},
    c1/.style={-stealth,very thick,red!80!black},
    v2/.style={-stealth,very thick,yellow!65!black},
    v4/.style={-stealth,very thick,purple!70!black}}
\node[dep] (0) at (0,0) {0};
\node[cli] (7) at (-1,-2) {7};
\node[spl] (8) at (2,-2) {8};
\draw[c1] (0) to[bend right] (7);
\draw[v2] (7) -- (8);
\draw[v4] (8) -- (2,-1) -- (0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use a `matrix` or whatever you want to add a legend

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,matrix} % Shadows for nodes
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{% This is the style settings for nodes
    dep/.style={circle,minimum size=#1,fill=orange!20,draw=orange,
                general shadow={fill=gray!60,shadow xshift=1pt,shadow yshift=-1pt}},
    dep/.default=1cm,
    cli/.style={circle,minimum size=#1,fill=white,draw,
                general shadow={fill=gray!60,shadow xshift=1pt,shadow yshift=-1pt}},
    cli/.default=1cm,
    spl/.style={cli=#1,append after command={
                  node[circle,draw,dotted,
                       minimum size=1.5cm] at (\tikzlastnode.center) {}}},
    spl/.default=1cm,
    c1/.style={-stealth,very thick,red!80!black},
    v2/.style={-stealth,very thick,yellow!65!black},
    v4/.style={-stealth,very thick,purple!70!black}}
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=graph]
    \node[dep] (0) at (0,0) {0};
    \node[cli] (7) at (-1,-2) {7};
    \node[spl] (8) at (2,-2) {8};
    \draw[c1] (0) to[bend right] (7);
    \draw[v2] (7) -- (8);
    \draw[v4] (8) -- (2,-1) -- (0);
\end{scope}
\matrix[draw,anchor=north west,xshift=1ex,matrix of nodes,row sep=.5ex,
        column 2/.style={text width=2.5cm,align=left,anchor=center}] 
at (graph.north east) {
    \draw[c1] (-.5,0) -- (.5,0); & $C_1$\\
    \draw[v2] (-.5,0) -- (.5,0); & $V_2$\\
    \draw[v4] (-.5,0) -- (.5,0); & $V_4$\\
    \draw[dotted] circle (.25);  & Split Delivery\\
    \node[cli=.5cm] {};          & Cliente\\
    \node[dep=.5cm] {};          & Deposito\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It seems that you haven't known much about Ti*k*Z yet, then [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15779/156344) on TeX.SE may be useful to you.

Comment: I've achieved made my graph following your example, but I have another doubt, how can I make the legends as in the right-top side of my picture? Is it that even possible on latex? and thanks for your help, you are cool, greetings from Chile, South America.

Comment: @HctorAlonsoHormazbalVildsol A legend added